# access violation after creating object inheriting from TRemotable

Tags: web-services, delphi, interface, access-violation

I'm new to web services and I'm getting an access violation in my client application on this line:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  req: G110Request;
begin
  req := G110Request.Create;
  req.Header.UserSoftware.name_ := 'somename';//AV!
  //...
end;
```

The class G110Request eventually is a TRemotable object:

```
G110Request = class(I1_SinglePack_Type)
  private
  public
    constructor Create; override;
  published
end;

I1_SinglePack_Type = class(Header_Type)
  private
    FBody: RequestData_Type;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property Body: RequestData_Type  read FBody write FBody;
end;

Header_Type = class(TRemotable)
  private
    FHeader: RequestHeaderData_Type;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property Header: RequestHeaderData_Type  read FHeader write FHeader;
end;

  RequestHeaderData_Type = class(TRemotable)
  private
    FAuth: RequestAuthHeaderData_Type;
    FUserSoftware: UserSoftware_Type;
    FTransaction: RequestTransactionHeaderData_Type;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property Auth:         RequestAuthHeaderData_Type         read FAuth write FAuth;
    property UserSoftware: UserSoftware_Type                  read FUserSoftware write FUserSoftware;
    property Transaction:  RequestTransactionHeaderData_Type  read FTransaction write FTransaction;
  end;

constructor G110Request.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  FSerializationOptions := [xoLiteralParam];
end;
```

Is there a special convention for TRemotable classes or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Header is most likely nil, unless you create it in G110Request.Create.

Comment: Use the debugger to step into the constructor. Does it create the `UserType` member? There's nothing in the code you posted that indicates when and where it is created.

Comment: It does not create Header and Body (they are nil).  When I create them myself (in TForm1.Button1Click), they both become valid, however all member objects (eg: UserSoftware) of Header and Body are not created.  Is it normal that the constructors are not coded when using the WSDL importer?  Does it mean all those constructors for each class need to be written after using WSDL importer?

Comment: Solved: I solved it by writing the appropriate code in the constructors.  Still find it strange that the wsdl importer did not do this...